# Tikz: Configure distance between two specific bars in a group of bars

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I have a grouped bar chart as follows below.

I'd like there to be a slightly bigger distance between every red and blue bar. Of course, I could just add another white bar between the red and the blue one - but that's not a very clean solution and messed up the legend (I've tried using `forget plot` here, but it makes the whole bar disappear). Any ideas how to do this would be highly appreaciated.

[image: example]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable} % plots
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ymax=100,
        ymin=0,
        ybar,
        xtick=data,
        legend style={at={(0.39,0.97)},
           anchor=north,legend columns=2},
        x tick label style={rotate=35,anchor=east},
        symbolic x coords={A, B, C}, 
        bar width=9pt, 
        enlarge x limits=0.2
        ]
                \addplot+[ybar, fill=green] plot coordinates {
                (A, 58.83)
                (B, 50.50)
                (C, 63.67)
                }; 
                \addplot+[ybar, fill=red] plot coordinates {
                (A, 37.83)
                (B, 45.75)
                (C, 34.92)
                };
                \addplot+[ybar, fill=blue] plot coordinates {
                (A, 70.17)
                (B, 59.50)
                (C, 75.17)
                }; 
                 \addplot+[ybar, fill=yellow] plot coordinates {
                (A, 28.50)
                (B, 38.67)
                (C, 23.75)
                };
     \legend{\strut 1st, \strut 2nd, \strut 3rd, \strut 4th}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable} % plots
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ymax=100,
        ymin=0,
        ybar,
        xtick=data,
        legend style={at={(0.39,0.97)},
        anchor=north,legend columns=2},
        x tick label style={rotate=35,anchor=east},
        symbolic x coords={A, B, C}, 
        bar width=9pt, 
        enlarge x limits=0.2
        ]
                \addplot+[ybar, fill=green, bar shift=-20 pt] plot coordinates {
                (A, 58.83)
                (B, 50.50)
                (C, 63.67)
                }; 
                \addplot+[ybar, fill=red, bar shift=-8 pt] plot coordinates {
                (A, 37.83)
                (B, 45.75)
                (C, 34.92)
                };
                \addplot+[ybar, fill=blue, bar shift=8 pt] plot coordinates {
                (A, 70.17)
                (B, 59.50)
                (C, 75.17)
                }; 
                 \addplot+[ybar, fill=yellow, bar shift=20 pt] plot coordinates {
                (A, 28.50)
                (B, 38.67)
                (C, 23.75)
                };
     \legend{\strut 1st, \strut 2nd, \strut 3rd, \strut 4th}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Bar graph with three sets of four bars]

Comment: That did it. Many thanks!